# Linux server with . and .. directories

Tags: linux, unix, directory, root, hidden-files

Why does each folder directory in my linux server has . and .. directories with same files ? is it user error or by design ?

[image]

Example: I have folder bladelogic with list of these files along with . and .. directories which contains same files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` refers to the current directory and `..` refers to the parent directory. This is by design.

Answer (score 2):

this is by design. `.` refers to the current directory and `..` refers to the directory "above" the current one. Specifically, suppose you're in a directory `/foo/bar/wizzle`. If you do an `ls` in there you'll see `.`, which refers to `/foo/bar/wizzle`, and a `..` which refers to `/foo/bar`. You can check this by running `ls .` (which will give you the same result as just `ls`) and `ls ..` which will show you the contents fo